# Working with byte array and strings

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am working with byte arrays and strings. I have a byte array that I modify and then use to generate a string. I have looked at lots of posts on this website that recommend using `BlockCopy` or `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString();` I have tried those but for some reason the string I am getting has all gibberish characters.

Here is the problem and what i expect. Lets say i have hex encoded string of bytes as follows:

```
string str = "f20bdba6ff29eed7b046d1df9fb70000";
```

Corresponding array is:

```
byte[] arrayStr = new byte[] { 0xf2, 0x0b, 0xdb, 0xa6, 0xff, 0x29, 0xee, 0xd7, 0xb0, 0x46, 0xd1, 0xdf, 0x9f, 0xb7, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

Please note that 2 characters in above string represent byte.

Now, lets say I manipulate `arrayStr` and change the byte at array index 4 (0xff) to (0xe1). I want that I should be able to get a string such that:

> string str = "f20bdba6**e1**29eed7b046d1df9fb70000";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx):

```
string str = BitConverter.ToString(arrayStr).Replace("-", "");
```